Unable to access a folder that does not belong to Wordpress installation
I have a Wordpress site for which I have added an html folder with many files on the server.
When I try to access the content of this folder, for example mywebsite.fr/my-html-folder/index.html, there is a redirection to mywebsite.fr/index.html, the name folder is automatically deleted from the url ...
Do you know where this could be coming from? Maybe a wordpress security?
here is my htacess :
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE "application/atom+xml" "application/javascript" "application/json" "application/ld+json" "application/manifest+json" "application/rdf+xml" "application/rss+xml" "application/schema+json" "application/vnd.geo+json" "application/vnd.ms-fontobject" "application/x-font-ttf" "application/x-javascript" "application/x-web-app-manifest+json" "application/xhtml+xml" "application/xml" "font/eot" "font/opentype" "image/bmp" "image/svg+xml" "image/vnd.microsoft.icon" "image/x-icon" "text/cache-manifest" "text/css" "text/html" "text/javascript" "text/plain" "text/vcard" "text/vnd.rim.location.xloc" "text/vtt" "text/x-component" "text/x-cross-domain-policy" "text/xml"

# SECTION BEGIN GIT PROTECTION
RedirectMatch 404 /\.git
# SECTION END GIT PROTECTION


# BEGIN WPSuperCache

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

